# Evaluating a polynomial at a root of unity?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n+1)$ be the $2n$th cyclotomic ring (for $n$ a power of $2$ in which case $\Phi_{2n}(x) = x^n+1$). Let $g$ be an $n$-dimensional vector chosen at random from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ according to the discrete gaussian distribution with parameter $s$ defined as follows.
For any real $s>0$, define the (spherical) Gaussian function $\rho_{s} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow (0,1]$ with parameter $s$ as:

$\forall \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \rho_{s}(\vec{x})=\exp(-\pi \langle\vec{x},\vec{x}\rangle/s^2) = \exp(-\pi \|\vec{x}\|^2/s^2).$

For any real $s > 0$, define the (spherical) discrete Gaussian distribution over $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as:

$\forall \vec{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n, D_{Z^n,s}(\vec{x})= \frac{\rho_{s}(\vec{x})}{\rho_{s}(\mathbb{Z}^n)},$

where $\rho_s(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ is equal to $\sum_{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n} \rho_s(\vec{x})$.

This vector $g$ is then viewed as a polynomial where the ith component of the vector is seen as the coefficient of the term $x^{i-1}$. Now viewing this g as a polynomial if we evaluate this polynomial at a root of unity then this value will be complex.

My question is what is the probability that $|g(\omega)| < \epsilon$ where $\omega$ is a root of the polynomial $x^n +1$ (that is $\omega$ is a primitive $2n$th root of unity) for some $\epsilon < 1$.

Comment: How do you chose a polynomial from $Z^n$?

Comment: @martycohen: presumably, Siitd means that the coefficients are each being chosen from $\mathbb{Z}$, and thus, because there are $n$ coefficients, one can represent the coefficients as a vector, $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: My question is, given that you're working in an integer-based system, what is $\epsilon$? And does $\omega$ exist within the cyclotomic ring?

Comment: I meant that n-dimensional vector is chosen from Z^n and the this vector is then viewed as polynomial, where the ith component of the vector is seen as the coefficient of the x^i term in the polynomial.

Comment: @GlenO: The output $g(\omega)$ will be a complex number and $\epsilon$ is some value less than $1$. $\omega$ is complex and will not be in the cyclotomic ring.

Comment: @GlenO: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: So what you're saying is that your cyclotomic ring is just being used to define your polynomial, and then the question itself is operating within the field of complex numbers?

Comment: Yes. The the evaluation of $g$ at $n$ roots of unity correspond to the $n$ complex embeddings from the number field $K = Q[x]/x^n+1$ to $C^n$.

Comment: This question requires an urgent editing to add all the missing/wrong data.

Comment: Voting not to close. This is a good question (but the OP should, indeed, incorporate  all the additional explanations to the body of the question so that they are immediately visible to all). Basically asking about the probability that a random integer of this cyclotomic integer has small complex norm in a given embedding. I could think of telecommunications applications where this question is relevant. But pardon my ignorance - what is a discrete gaussian distribution?

Comment: @Siitd: Are you sure you mean $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^n + 1)$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}[x] / \Phi_{2n}(x)$, where $\Phi_{2n}$ is the cyclotomic polynomial whose roots are the *primitive* $2n$-th roots of unity?

Comment: I have updated the question to address the comments. @JyrkiLahtonen: I included a definition of a discrete gaussian distribution in the question.@Hurkly: I am interested in the case when $n$ is a power of two. In that case $\Phi_{2n}(x)$ is exactly $x^{n} + 1$.